# Rails HABTM model on heroku is showing "model_id", "name" and "timestamp" instead of simply "name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, has-and-belongs-to-many

This must be quite simple, but I just can't find a way.

I have 2 models with HABTM relationship.

Trip.rb

```
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

Category.rb

```
    has_and_belongs_to_many :trips
```

Trip index.html.erb

```
    <%= trip.categories %>
```

everything is fine on my local machine - I see only the category name.

But when I deploy to heroku, instead of category name I see

```
 [#<Category id: 1, name: "Surfing", created_at: "2011-10-20 12:28:57", updated_at: "2011-10-20 12:28:57">]
```

Anyone knows how to fix this ?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would see the `name` locally, but what you're seeing on Heroku is the result of `to_s` being implicitly called on the `trip.categories` association, which is an array of category records.

```
# You could define the `to_s` of Category to return the name.
class Category
  def to_s
    name
  end
end

# or define a method to return a mapping of the category names:
class Trip
  # via an association extension
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories do
    def names
      map(&:name)
    end
  end

  # or a simple instance method
  def category_names
    categories.map(&:name)
  end
end

Trip.first.categories.names #=> [cat1, cat2]
Trip.first.category_names   #=> [cat1, cat2]
```

But your current template is still going to drop an `Array` of strings into the output, like:

```
["category1", "category2", "category3"]
```

What you probably want is more like:

```
<%= trip.categories.map(&:name).to_sentence %>
```

Which would result in: "category1, category2, and category3", or some such.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it works. I had already defined the `to_s`of Category, probably that's why I could see the name locally. Anyway thank you!